# How do you split long exec commands up?

Tags: ruby, exec, capistrano

in ruby when you are writing a deploy script say in capistrano, you can use `exec` to run commands, how ever what do you do when you have an exec line this long:

```
exec 'bundle exec promiscuous publish "Xaaron::User.all" && bundle exec promiscuous publish "Xaaron::Role.all" && bundle exec promiscuous publish "Xaaron::Permission.all" && bundle exec promiscuous publish "Xaaron::ApiKey.all"'
```

It works, it runs, it does what I want, but I have to add more to it. And its a bit long. So how do I break it up into multiple lines and still have it run normally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split string up into separate lines:

```
exec "bundle install && " +
     "apt-get install nginx && " +
     "cat file"
```

Answer (score 4):

What about

```
exec [
  'bundle exec promiscuous publish "Xaaron::User.all"',
  'bundle exec promiscuous publish "Xaaron::Role.all"',
  'bundle exec promiscuous publish "Xaaron::Permission.all"',
  'bundle exec promiscuous publish "Xaaron::ApiKey.all"',
].join(" && ")
```

or in this particular case,

```
exec %w[User Role Permission ApiKey]
.map{|e| "bundle exec promiscuous publish \"Xaaron::#{e}.all\""}.join(" && ")
```